# How to remove weird errors deleting something from a file using NodeJS + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

**This question is for knowledge about how NodeJS handles HTTP responses**

I'm trying to delete a field from a json file, using NodeJS and AngularJS.
The delete works, but there are two problems:

- The view in the fronted doesn't get updated after the json modification (the POST function, using `$scope.$apply` works and updates the view)
- refreshing the page shows the `delete error` window (why not in the current page?), but dismissing the window show the list without the selected element

What's happening, in short:
Lista (my JSON) contains A, B, C, D element -> delete(B)-> F5-> "Delete error"-> Lista contains A, C, D

My controller:

```
$scope.remove = function (daRimuovere) {
        var del = $scope.lista3.indexOf(daRimuovere);
        $http.delete('http://localhost/delete/' + del)
            .then(function () {
                $http.get('http://localhost/files/lista.json')
                    .then(
                    function (result) {
                        $scope.lista3 = result.data;
                    },
                    function () {
                        window.alert('Errore get!');
                    });
                window.alert('Delete success');
                $scope.$apply;
            },
            function () {
                window.alert('Errore delete');
            }
        )
    };
```

My NodeJS function

```
server.delete('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
    jsonfile.readFile('./public/lista.json', function (err, obj) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log('id= '+ req.params.id);
            obj.splice(req.params.id, 1);
        }
        jsonfile.writeFile('./public/lista.json', obj, function (err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else {
                console.log(obj);
                obj = JSON.stringify(obj, null, "\t");
            }
        })

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, in case someone gets strange errors from NodeJS.
The error in the Delete function is I'm not returning an HTTP explicit response, so Angular doesn't know if everything went well on the server.
My solution was this:

```
(...)
jsonfile.readFile('./public/lista.json', function (err, obj) {
if (err)
    console.log(err);
else {
    console.log('id= '+ req.params.id);
    obj.splice(req.params.id, 1);
    res.sendStatus(200); //this sends a OK from the server
}
```